# Swift: ¿Cual es la mejor manera de manejar cambios en un servidor de base de datos desde una App?

Tags: base-de-datos, swift, server

Perdón si mi pregunta es repetida pero estuve buscando de muchas maneras sin encontrar lo que necesito.

Tengo una App que guarda, actualiza y elimina registros en una base de datos local (Core Data para ser exactos), pero también necesito que esos cambios se vean reflejados en un servidor de base de datos para posteriormente actualizar el resto de usuarios que usan la app, algo así como una colaboración de tareas. Hasta este punto todo bien, cuando un usuario hace un cambio en la app, también se refleja en el servidor.
Ahora viene lo complejo (para mi claro je), si un usuario por alguna razón no tiene acceso a internet, evidentemente los cambios solo se logran en la app y el servidor ni se entera, allí es donde aparecen mis preguntas:

¿Cual es la mejor manera de hacer estos cambios en el servidor?

¿Como hago que se envíe nuevamente la petición al servidor con los datos que el usuario ya guardo en local pero no en el servidor?

¿Como administro cuales cambios si se enviaron al servidor y cuales no para intentarlo nuevamente?

He leído que teniendo un registro de que cosas están pendientes de enviar, eso es evidente, pero cual es la mejor estrategia, una tabla con los datos, una archivo, la misma app puede gestionar cuales peticiones no terminaron en éxito y volver a intentar...

Dejo uno de mis métodos simples por si de algo sirve:

```
func updateGeneralRemarksInServer(id_category: Int, value: String, controller: UIViewController){
        let valueUtf = value.data(using: .utf8)
        let value64 = valueUtf?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        
        let url = Server.URL + "updateGeneralRemarks.php?ic=\(id_category)&v=\(value64!)"
        let objUrl = URL(string: url)
        let tarea = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: objUrl!){ (datos,respuesta,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Internet Connection: \(error!._code)") // 1009
            }else{
                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: datos!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
                    let isError = json["error"] as! Int
                    if isError == 0{
                        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                            print("SUD") // Server Update Done
                        })
                    }else{
                        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Something went wrong", message: "Complete all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                            controller.present(alert, animated: true)
                        })
                    }
                }catch{print("JSON error")}
            }
        }
        tarea.resume()
    }
```

Espero alguien pueda por lo menos orientarme en la dirección correcta.

Comment: 1. Debes usar `SCNetworkReachability` para saber si vuelves de offline a online https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift. 2. Debes manejar estados en tu bdd; si pierdes conexión almacenas con `offline`, al volver la conexión buscas ese estado, envías al servidor y cambias a `online` en tu local.

Comment: Para el primer punto cual opción es mejor SCNetworkReachability o NWPathMonitor?
Para el Segundo punto es una propuesta interesante usar un campo para definir el estatus del registro.

Comment: Mejor `NWPathMonitor` que es relativamente nuevo y simple.